# Динамические поля формы в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Доброе время суток. Нужно сделать форму, в которой поле содержит два варианта ответа типа Radio Да/Нет и в случае Нет позволяет самому ввести ответ в появившийся инпут типа textbox. Своего рода пункт Другое как в бумажных анкетах. Мануал курил, понял мало. PHP и иже с ним знаю, не знаю только Bitrix. Как проще реализовать, через свой валидатор или есть нативный способ в расширенном режиме. И да - потом форма отправляется почтой, поэтому поле должно выдать или ДА или ДРУГОЕ %usertext%. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через jQuery. Если выбран ответ ДА то скрывать поле, если НЕТ то показывать. Отправляться оно будет в любом случае.

```
$('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $('#text').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#text').show();
    }
});
```

Пример кода - https://jsfiddle.net/hcj2nja9/

Comment: Можно ещё воспользоваться модулем веб-форм, чтобы не писать весь функционал с нуля. И уже в шаблоне компонента [form.result.new](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/service/form/components_2/form_result_new.php) при помощи jQuery показывать/скрывать поле.